# Archaic Stata v7 Code with Odd Macro References

Tags: stata

I'm working with data from ICPSR for which a `do` file was written in Stata V7, around 2001. The `do` file notes that the program only runs in Version 7 (which is true). I'm having issues understanding parts of the code and I'm wondering if any of you more knowledgeable folks can help.

Here's an example block of the code:

```
program drop _all;
program define impact1;

scalar drop _all;

*First define proportions in your sample;

qui reg svy_cmove [pweight=`8'] if `1'~=. & t_exp_vs_ph==1;
scalar define ptmove=_b[_cons];

qui reg svy_cmove [pweight=`8'] if `1'~=. & t_s8_vs_ph==1;
scalar define ps8move=_b[_cons];

qui reg `6'  [pweight=`8'] if `1'~=.;
scalar define tprop=_b[_cons];

qui reg `7' [pweight=`8'] if `1'~=.;
scalar defin s8prop=_b[_cons];

*Need to svyset data to specify weight;

svyset pweight `8' ;
```

The code runs fine and performs what it is supposed to (replication of a table from a study), but what I don't understand is what the numbered references mean, for instance,

```
pweight= `8'
```

It refers to a total weight used in the survey, but I don't know how Stata makes the connection between the reference

```
`8'
```

and the proper weight variable. Note that it is NOT defined at any point earlier in the do file. The code uses these references throughout the file when it runs a series of regressions to replicate the tables produced by the research team.

Any insight into how this process operates would be helpful so I can understand how Stata makes the connection between the variable and the number.

Comment: Hi, AXG, and welcome to the site!  Unfortunately, this is really a Stata question, not a statistics question, and you'd almost certainly be better served on stackoverflow (the programmer site) than here (the statistics site.)  Either way, it looks like a real puzzle, and I hope you find an answer somewhere.

Comment: I agree with @jorpppp. On the evidence here there is nothing archaic about this code; it is just that how to call it is not documented here. By the way, a statement `version 7` (if that is implied here) means that `version 7` of Stata (or greater) is required, **not** that it will run **only** in version 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just positional arguments. 1 refers to the first word written after the program command, 2 to the second and so on. This is still standard in Stata

Here's an example

```
clear
program define positions
    di "`1'"
    di "`2'"
    di "`3'"
end
positions one two three
```

Presumably when you call the `impact1` program, the eighth argument is the probability weight.

Comment: Thanks, jorpppp. I scrolled down the code to where the impact1 program is called, and it says this:
     impact1 m_hsg_cost "$covars" "" e(N) 0 t_exp_vs_ph t_s8_vs_ph wt_Totsvy ;

which would be consistent with 8 being the weight, 7 being the control, 6 being the treatment, down to 1 being the outcome variable of interest. I've never seen code written this way where the argument referenced isn't defined until later in the file; this is definitely useful to know. Thank you!!

Comment: The use of positional arguments carries over a practice good for do-files to programs. It is well documented in [U] e.g. see 16.4.1 in http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u.pdf